# how to get drive capacity in oracle java

Tags: java, ios, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to get the capacity of the drive `c:` in oracle, for this i'm using java, but i had some troubles, because in oracle File io class it is not working as expected. This is my sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED TEST.DISKS_FREE as 
  import java.io.File;
  import java.sql.*;

  public class DiskFreeSpace
  {
     public static long loadDisk() throws SQLException
     {
        File file = new File("c:");
        long freeSpace = file.getFreeSpace();
        return freeSpace;
  }
}
```

When i compile this code, throw this error:

```
[Error]  (0: 0): DISKS_FREE:14: cannot find symbol
[Error]  (0: 0): symbol  : method getFreeSpace()
[Error]  (0: 0): location: class java.io.File
[Error]  (0: 0):         long freeSpace = file.getFreeSpace();
[Error]  (0: 0):                              ^
[Error]  (0: 0): 1 error
```

This means that compliler doesn't find method `getFreeSpace()` in java.io.File, however if i test this in java (jdk6) , is working perfect. I'm using oracle 11gr2 by the way.

Comment: JDK 6? Really? If you were using JDK 7+ there'd be a way... But not with 6.

Comment: hi, @fge. I test this code in java6, and java5 and both have getFreeSpace() method for java.io.File. The problem is with oracle, that i don't know why is giving the above error.

Answer (score 1):

You have and other methods(ways) to Find the Free Space:

```
import java.io.File;

public class DiskSpaceDetail
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    File file = new File("c:");
    long totalSpace = file.getTotalSpace(); //total disk space in bytes.
    long usableSpace = file.getUsableSpace(); ///unallocated / free disk space in bytes.
    long freeSpace = file.getFreeSpace(); //unallocated / free disk space in bytes.

    System.out.println(" === Partition Detail ===");

    System.out.println(" === bytes ===");
    System.out.println("Total size : " + totalSpace + " bytes");
    System.out.println("Space free : " + usableSpace + " bytes");
    System.out.println("Space free : " + freeSpace + " bytes");

    System.out.println(" === mega bytes ===");
    System.out.println("Total size : " + totalSpace /1024 /1024 + " mb");
    System.out.println("Space free : " + usableSpace /1024 /1024 + " mb");
    System.out.println("Space free : " + freeSpace /1024 /1024 + " mb");
}
}
```

Let me know if that works in your case..

Comment: In fact, i'm using part of this code, in java works ok, but in an oracle environment doesn't. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Btw, why do you think that Oracle uses jdk6? For example, Oracle 10g uses jdk4.

There is yet another thing you does not consider. When using intra-database java stored procedure, you have no permissions to access file system by default. You should grant this using dbms_java.

Comment: thanks for answer Sanders, but which permmissions i should grant?

Comment: It should be written in the getFreeSpace() jdk documentation. Otherwise, when you'll can to successfully compile a function, just call it - exception message will say permissions required.